# simple SQLite query

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

How would I query these 4 tables to see actors who are in *Apocalypse Now*?

```
Studio Table
studioID  studioName
--------  --------
1         Lucasfilm
2         Amblin Entertainment
3         Zoetrope Studios

Movie Table
movieID   movieName        studioID    castID
--------  --------        --------    --------
1         Star Wars            1          1
2         Indiana Jones        1          2
3         Back to the Future   2          3
4         Apocalypse Now       3          4

Cast Table
castID   movieID  actorID  roleName
-------- -------- -------- --------
1          1         1     Han Solo
2          2         1     Indiana Jones
3          3         3     Doc Brown
4          4         1     Colonel Lucas
5          4         2     Tyrone Miller

Actor Table
actorID  lastName     firstName
-------- --------     --------
1        Ford         Harrison
2        Fishburne    Laurence
3        Lloyd        Christopher
```

Right now I'm thinking:

```
SELECT Studio.studioName, Movie.movieName, Cast.roleName, Actor.firstName, Actor.lastname
FROM Studio, Movie, Actor, Cast 

WHERE Cast.castID = Movie.castID and Movie.movieName = 'Apocalypse Now'

ORDER BY Actor.lastname
```

Not really sure how to join the tables.

=.=.=.=.=.=.=.=.=

Comment: You need to use inner joins. Read up on them and you should be able to form your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Movie m
LEFT JOIN Cast c on (c.movieID = m.movieID)
LEFT JOIN Actor a on (a.actorID = c.actorID)
WHERE m.movieName='Apocalypse Now';
```

if you need also a Studio join the studio table:

```
SELECT a.actorID, a.firstName, a.lastName, s.studioName
FROM Movie m
LEFT JOIN Cast c on (c.movieID = m.movieID)
LEFT JOIN Actor a on (a.actorID = c.actorID)
LEFT JOIN Studio s on (m.studioID = s.studioID)
WHERE m.movieName='Apocalypse Now';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And if I wanted to also return the related Studio, Movie, and role along with the Actors? I'm googling it now but I don't know what's happening with your a.* and Movie m. I'm trying to wrap my mind around it so that I could use a similar query to, for instance, find movies Harrison Ford is in.

Comment: You can replace a.* with a.actorID, a.firstName, a.lastName this is equal in this case (a.* means all columns from a).

Comment: But I can't SELECT a.actorID, a.firstName, a.lastName x.studioName FROM Movie m, Studio ?

Comment: You have to join a Studio table first: LEFT JOIN Studio s on (m.studioID=s.studioID) -> just like other joins you made...

Comment: I'm sorry - it's very very basic query in sql. Try to find some online tutorials and start learning! Good luck!